# SElinux preventing PostgreSQL launch

Tags: linux, postgresql, selinux

I'm trying to set up an Oracle server with postgres but everytime i try to execute the command "sudo systemctl start postgresql" an error pops up and i cannot start the database. Attached you can find a screenshot with a detailed log of the problem:

[image: error log]

Based upon this error log i found that the problem is related to SElinux and that disabling it allows the database to start correctly. Is it possible to solve this problem without disabling SElinux?

I also tried to find the shared library that is causing the problem but as you can see from the error log after the "error while loading shared libraries: " part there is no indication of the specific shared library causing the problem.

The database was installed in the default directory "/var/lib/pgsql" and no changes to the configuration files were made before the error popped up.

---

I tried to get the AVC log as suggested by one user and this is the message that is shown:

[image]

---

I found the solution to this problem: when i configured postgres for the first time i downloaded it from a preinstalled repository and i didn't notice that the package downloaded was still version 10 of postgres. Today i removed completely the old version and installed current one from the official postgres repository. Now everything works properly when setting SElinux to enforcing

Comment: here is a way how to do it with selinux enabled
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/error-cannot-restore-segment-prot-after-reloc-permission-denied-during-linux-installation

Comment: I tried the solution in the link you posted but i think that it is specific for the IBM ClearQuest program. In the link they apply the chcon command to the libcqlic.so file but i don't have it in my server

Comment: What distro **are** you using?

Comment: I'm currently using Oracle Linux 8

Comment: What are the AVC messages ? See [Troubleshooting Access-Denial Messages](https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/selinux/ol-s2-syssec.html), update your post with more details if you still need help, or write down an answer if you find something.

Comment: I don't have any experience w/ Oracle Linux, or setting up postgres under SELinuxx - but does  [this](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/how-configure-selinux-postgresql-and-timescaledb) help?